# Load libaries given subsite name in clientapi

Tags: 2010, development, client-object-model, .net

Hi I'm fairly new to the sharepoint client api, but I'm trying to get the libraries given a site name. My clientcontext in my class is at the root of my sharepoint e.g. https://mysharepoint.abc.com and I load the root e.g.

```
        public SharePointHelper(String url, String username, String password, String domain)
    {
        mClientContext = new ClientContext(url);
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
        mClientContext.Credentials = credentials;
        mRootWeb = mClientContext.Web;
        mClientContext.Load(mRootWeb);
    }
```

Now how would I go about getting a subsite web object given its name e.g.

```
        public Web GetWebByTitle(String siteTitle)
    {
        var query = mClientContext.LoadQuery(
            mRootWeb.Webs.Where(p => p.Title == siteTitle));
        mClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The above is always retuning null when DEF is passed e.g. My sharepoint is laid out like the following:

https://mysharepoint.abc.com
 -ABC - site
   DEF - sub site of ABC
      AA - LIBRARY of DEF
      BB - LIBRARY of DEF
 
   GHI - sub site of ABC
   JKL - sub site of ABC

How can I get the libraries for a given site while I am at the root of the sharepoint site? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenWebById e.g.

```
        public ListCollection GetSiteLibraries(Guid siteId)
    {
        Web web = mClientContext.Site.OpenWebById(siteId);

        if (web != null)
        {
            mClientContext.Load(web.Lists);
            mClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            return web.Lists;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I stored the Id of the subsite and used this to get the site lists later